# Android Gridview item 0 onlickLister won't register

Tags: java, android, gridview

I have a gridview, it works perfectly except for the onlcick on the first item which doesn't register, if i scroll down a while and come back up then it does, if anyone has any ideas i'd really appreciate it....

Gridadapter: - the main constructers (getPosition etc) are all standard

```
public View setFriendGridItem(View view,Friend friend) {
    if(view == null) view = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.basic_friend_item, null);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,height);
    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    TextView nameView = view.findViewById(R.id.basic_friend_display_name);
    TextView statusView = view.findViewById(R.id.basic_friend_status);
    if(statusView.hasOnClickListeners())statusView.setOnClickListener(null);
    String status = friend.id%5 == 0 ? "outgoing" : (friend.id%3 == 0 ? "incoming" : friend.id%2==0?"confirmed": "");

    setFriendStatus(statusView,status,friend.id);
    nameView.setText(friend.displayName);
    return view;
}
```

the id doesn't do anything, it's only passed to track the logs - Util.Log is just writing out a log because i get fed up of writing String.valueof....

```
 public void setFriendStatus(TextView view, String status,final int id) {
    Util.logInt("66",id);
    switch(status.toLowerCase()) {
        case "outgoing":
            view.setText("Request sent");
            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Util.logStr("gridadapter 73","cancel request");Util.logInt("69",id);
                }
            });
            view.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.playdateLightGreen));
            break;
        case "incoming":
            view.setText("Wants to be friends");
            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Util.logStr("gridadapter 73","respond to request");Util.logInt("69",id);
                }
            });
            view.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.playdateLightGreen));
            break;
        case "confirmed":
            view.setText("Confirmed");
            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Util.logStr("gridadapter 84","remove friend");Util.logInt("69",id);
                }
            });
            view.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.playdateMainGreen));
            break;
        default:
            view.setText("Connect");
            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Util.logStr("gridadapter 94","send request");Util.logInt("69",id);
                }
            });
            view.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.playdateMainRed));
            break;

    }
}
```

at the moment the data is just sample data i'm hardcoding (while in the design phase) it's a basic item, i don't know if it would help to see it as it loads correctly etc but just say so and i can add it in

for those who love a logcat (before the first LOGI i hit the text view a few times, you can see at the bottom when i've come back up finally item 1 registers):

```
2019-03-07 18:13:46.982 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 1
2019-03-07 18:13:46.995 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 1
2019-03-07 18:13:47.007 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 2
2019-03-07 18:13:47.023 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 3
2019-03-07 18:13:47.039 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 4
2019-03-07 18:13:47.051 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 5
2019-03-07 18:13:47.065 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 6
2019-03-07 18:13:47.079 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 7
2019-03-07 18:13:47.096 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 8
2019-03-07 18:14:49.675 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI gridadapter 84: remove friend
2019-03-07 18:14:49.675 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 69: 4
2019-03-07 18:14:53.695 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI gridadapter 84: remove friend
2019-03-07 18:14:53.695 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 69: 2
2019-03-07 18:14:55.677 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI gridadapter 73: respond to request
2019-03-07 18:14:55.677 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 69: 3
2019-03-07 18:14:58.733 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI gridadapter 84: remove friend
2019-03-07 18:14:58.733 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 69: 4
2019-03-07 18:15:00.847 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 9
2019-03-07 18:15:00.851 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 10
2019-03-07 18:15:00.879 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 11
2019-03-07 18:15:00.882 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 12
2019-03-07 18:15:00.913 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 13
2019-03-07 18:15:00.916 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 14
2019-03-07 18:15:00.947 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 15
2019-03-07 18:15:00.949 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 16
2019-03-07 18:15:00.979 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 17
2019-03-07 18:15:00.982 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 18
2019-03-07 18:15:00.996 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 19
2019-03-07 18:15:00.999 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 20
2019-03-07 18:15:01.030 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 21
2019-03-07 18:15:01.033 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 22
2019-03-07 18:15:01.063 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 23
2019-03-07 18:15:01.066 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 24
2019-03-07 18:15:01.097 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 25
2019-03-07 18:15:01.099 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 26
2019-03-07 18:15:01.131 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 27
2019-03-07 18:15:01.133 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 28
2019-03-07 18:15:01.165 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 29
2019-03-07 18:15:01.167 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 30
2019-03-07 18:15:01.198 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 31
2019-03-07 18:15:01.201 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 32
2019-03-07 18:15:01.249 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 33
2019-03-07 18:15:01.251 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 34
2019-03-07 18:15:01.282 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 35
2019-03-07 18:15:01.285 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 36
2019-03-07 18:15:01.332 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 37
2019-03-07 18:15:01.335 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 38
2019-03-07 18:15:01.366 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 39
2019-03-07 18:15:01.368 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 40
2019-03-07 18:15:01.416 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 41
2019-03-07 18:15:01.419 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 42
2019-03-07 18:15:01.475 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 43
2019-03-07 18:15:01.490 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 44
2019-03-07 18:15:01.534 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 45
2019-03-07 18:15:01.536 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 46
2019-03-07 18:15:01.601 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 47
2019-03-07 18:15:01.603 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 48
2019-03-07 18:15:01.668 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 49
2019-03-07 18:15:01.670 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 50
2019-03-07 18:15:01.753 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 51
2019-03-07 18:15:01.756 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 52
2019-03-07 18:15:01.836 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 53
2019-03-07 18:15:01.840 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 54
2019-03-07 18:15:01.954 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 55
2019-03-07 18:15:01.957 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 56
2019-03-07 18:15:02.088 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 57
2019-03-07 18:15:02.091 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 58
2019-03-07 18:15:02.256 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 59
2019-03-07 18:15:02.259 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 60
2019-03-07 18:15:02.508 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 61
2019-03-07 18:15:02.511 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 62
2019-03-07 18:15:03.966 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI gridadapter 73: cancel request
2019-03-07 18:15:03.967 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 69: 60
2019-03-07 18:15:04.993 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 53
2019-03-07 18:15:04.995 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 54
2019-03-07 18:15:05.043 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 51
2019-03-07 18:15:05.045 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 52
2019-03-07 18:15:05.077 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 49
2019-03-07 18:15:05.078 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 50
2019-03-07 18:15:05.110 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 47
2019-03-07 18:15:05.112 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 48
2019-03-07 18:15:05.144 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 45
2019-03-07 18:15:05.146 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 46
2019-03-07 18:15:05.177 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 43
2019-03-07 18:15:05.179 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 44
2019-03-07 18:15:05.228 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 41
2019-03-07 18:15:05.231 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 42
2019-03-07 18:15:05.263 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 39
2019-03-07 18:15:05.266 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 40
2019-03-07 18:15:05.295 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 37
2019-03-07 18:15:05.298 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 38
2019-03-07 18:15:05.328 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 35
2019-03-07 18:15:05.332 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 36
2019-03-07 18:15:05.379 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 33
2019-03-07 18:15:05.381 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 34
2019-03-07 18:15:05.430 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 31
2019-03-07 18:15:05.432 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 32
2019-03-07 18:15:05.479 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 29
2019-03-07 18:15:05.482 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 30
2019-03-07 18:15:05.530 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 27
2019-03-07 18:15:05.532 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 28
2019-03-07 18:15:05.597 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 25
2019-03-07 18:15:05.599 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 26
2019-03-07 18:15:05.647 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 23
2019-03-07 18:15:05.651 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 24
2019-03-07 18:15:05.731 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 21
2019-03-07 18:15:05.734 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 22
2019-03-07 18:15:05.815 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 19
2019-03-07 18:15:05.818 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 20
2019-03-07 18:15:05.916 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 17
2019-03-07 18:15:05.918 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 18
2019-03-07 18:15:06.033 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 15
2019-03-07 18:15:06.036 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 16
2019-03-07 18:15:06.202 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 13
2019-03-07 18:15:06.205 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 14
2019-03-07 18:15:06.419 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 11
2019-03-07 18:15:06.422 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 12
2019-03-07 18:15:06.790 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 9
2019-03-07 18:15:06.792 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 10
2019-03-07 18:15:06.841 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 7
2019-03-07 18:15:06.842 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 8
2019-03-07 18:15:06.890 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 5
2019-03-07 18:15:06.891 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 6
2019-03-07 18:15:06.940 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 3
2019-03-07 18:15:06.943 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 4
2019-03-07 18:15:06.973 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 1
2019-03-07 18:15:06.976 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 2
2019-03-07 18:15:07.024 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 7
2019-03-07 18:15:07.026 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 66: 8
2019-03-07 18:15:08.083 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI gridadapter 94: send request
2019-03-07 18:15:08.084 2815-2815/com.localplaydatesandroid I/LOGI 69: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is having this problem, here is how I fixed it:

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View basicGrid, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    if(items.get(i) instanceof Friend) return setFriendGridItem((basicGrid == null), (Friend) items.get(i));
    return basicGrid;
}
```

so we check if the view at the current position is null or not (i.e. is it saved in memory still or has it been removed) and pass that boolean value to the setFriendGridItem method

Then in the method we say:

```
 public View setFriendGridItem(Boolean setClicks,final Friend friend) {
        View view = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.basic_friend_item, null);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,height);
        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        LinearLayout basic_profile = view.findViewById(R.id.basic_friend_profile);
        if(!setClicks) {
            basic_profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), FriendActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    intent.putExtra("friend", friend);
                    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
```

....

here we check if setClicks is false (i.e the view was null), and if it is then we can assign the clicks as they haven't been set yet (because there wasn't a view to set them to).

This works now on all the view from 0 to infinity (and beyond!).

What I think is happening is that for position 0 the view is drawn more than once (as the logs show) so the view is created and then recreated before the onclicks get registered, and then somewhere in those re-draws the onclicks get unregistered and the view isn't null so they aren't put back.

It doesn't 100% make sense to me, and its possibly just one of those anomalies that happens due to the lifecycle in Android - but if anyone else has this problem, then here is a solution.  And if anyone else with a deeper understanding of this could explain to me what's going on that would be fabulous.